# Laravel - black-bits/laravel-cognito-auth causing issues in default route

Tags: laravel

I've installed a laravel package *black-bits/laravel-cognito-auth* .
When i run `php artisan route:list` on command line, i've the following error:

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController] does not exist.

I'm not using ResetPasswordController in that specified path.
My ResetPassword controller's path is here: *\app\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Account\ResetPasswordController.php*.
I'm mainly using this project for apis.

when i search for this path in vendor folder, i can see this.
[image]
[image].

Since, these routes are in vendor folder, what can i do to fix this issue?

Comment: Dunno what black-bits package is, but usually laravel ships with the folder `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\*` and that's where the ResetPasswordController, among others, is. The error is saying that the file either does not exists or the name of the class has been changed.

Comment: I've moved the ResetPasswordController to \app\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Account\ResetPasswordController.php, and i'm using this new namespace for the routes, but the one inside the vendor uses the old one. if i comment those lines from vendor, then the error is gone.